# Performance measurement: time vs tick?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

**What is the best way to ensure that real-time performance are achieved, with a 2 thread program running on 1 or 2 cores ? boost::timer or RDTSC ?**

We started from that code

```
boost::timer t;
p.f(frame);
max_time_per_frame = std!::max(max_time_per_frame, t.ellapsed());

... where p is an instance of Proc.

class Proc {
public:
    Proc() : _frame_counter(0) {}

    // that function must be call for each video frame and take less than 1/fps seconds 
    // 24 fps => 1/24 => < 0.04 seconds.
    void f(unsigned char * const frame) 
    {
        processFrame(frame); //that's the most important part

        //that part run every 240 frame and should not affect
        // the processFrame flow !
        if(_frame_counter % 240 == 0) 
        {
            do_something_more();
        }
        _frame_counter++;
    }

private:
    _frame_counter;
}
```

So it run in a Single-Thread/Single-Core way and we observed that the max_time_per_frame is higher than the target time because of the `do_something_more` processing.
To remove those processing time spikes, we started every `do_something_more` in a separate thread, like in the pseudo-code below.

```
class Proc {
public:
    Proc() : _frame_counter(0) {
        t = start_thread ( do_something_more_thread );
    }

    // that function must be call for each video frame and take less than 1/fps seconds 
    // 24 fps => 1/24 => < 0.04 seconds.
    void f(unsigned char * const frame) 
    {
        processFrame(frame); //that's the most important part

        //that part run every 240 frame and should not affect
        // the processFrame flow !
        if(_frame_counter % 240 == 0) 
        {
            sem.up();
        }
        _frame_counter++;
    }

    void do_something_more_thread()
    {
       while(1)
       {
            sem.down();
            do_something_more();
       }
    }

private:
    _frame_counter;
    semaphore sem; 
    thread t;
}
```

I always start my program on 1 and 2 core. So i use `start /AFFINITY 1 pro.exe` or `start /AFFINITY 3 prog.exe`
And from time point of view, every thing is ok, `max_time_per_frame` stay below our target, close to the average at 0.02 second/frame.

But if I dump the number of tick spent in f, using RDTSC.

```
#include <intrin.h>
...
unsigned long long getTick()
{
    return __rdtsc();
}

void f(unsigned char * const frame) 
{
    s = getTick();

    processFrame(frame); //that's the most important part

    //that part run every 240 frame and should not affect
    // the processFrame flow !
    if(_frame_counter % 240 == 0) 
    {
        sem.up();
    }
    _frame_counter++;

    e = getTick();
    dump(e - s);
}
```

`start /AFFINITY 3 prog.exe` the max_tick_per_frame was stable and as expected i saw 1 thread(100% of 1 core) and the 2nd thread started at a normal pace on the 2nd core.

`start /AFFINITY 1 pro.exe`, i saw only 1 core at 100% (as expected), but the `do_something_more` computation time doesn't seem spead over the time, interleaved thread execution. In fact, at regular interval, i saw a huge spike of the tick count.

**So the question is why ? does the only interesting measure is `time` ? does `tick`have sense when running sofware on 1 core (frequency boost) ?**

Comment: I've just respond to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089219/obtaining-time-from-clock-cycles

Comment: I make this comment in response to seeing mention of .exe file extensions. My apologies apply if you're not using Windows. Simply put, you can't - MS Windows is not a Real Time Operating System (RTOS) - you can get close, but _never_ real-time with windows.

Comment: @zaufi, it looks similar but my results are reversed, running the soft on 1 or 2 core doesn't really change the `time`, but when running/scheduling the 2 thread on 1 core, the number of `tick` increase for 1 frame and not for several, like if the additional thread execution time was not spread/interleaved during the Real--Time processing of the next frame.

Comment: Are you aware of the numerous problems of RDTSC even on a real-time OS? I don't think it's a good option for timing anything even in very specific and controlled environment (which doesn't appear to be a given).

Comment: I don't see any code here to change the thread priority to 'real-time'. Your program should be more stable with this option enabled in both threads. That said, the windows scheduler isn't guaranteed to give identical time slots to processes / threads.

Comment: @enhzflep, i think everyone will agree that window is not a RTOS, but in the real-life, a lot of software must run within windows and process video stream, video encoding from capture card, etc... From here, being real-time just means that you don't lost a frame (observed & measured, it's not an absolute proof...) :)

Comment: @Serdalis, i think you are on a good way. In fact, i create a library and an integrator is responsible of using it in a more complex soft and workflow. BUT you say that if can set the priority to REALTIME or calling SetPriorityClass(progHdl, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS) from my code, the time slot of each thread will be identical and interleaved at a correct pace ? I will try, let see ....

Comment: RDTSC does not measure time at all, insofar if you're interested in timing, the answer is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you'll never get true real time performance out of windows, you can reduce the pitfalls of RDTSC by using the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is a small code chunk that takes advantage of the API.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double timeTaken;
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER firstCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER endCount;
    /*-- give us the higheest priority avaliable --*/
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
    /*-- get the frequency of the timer we are using --*/
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);  
    /*-- get the timers current tick --*/
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&firstCount);
    /*-- some pause --*/
    Sleep(1);
    /*-- get the timers current tick --*/
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCount);
    /*-- calculate time passed --*/
    timeTaken = (double)(doubleendCount.QuadPart-firstCount.QuadPart)/(double)(frequency.QuadPart/1000);

    printf("Time: %lf", timeTaken);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also use:

```
#include <Mmsystem.h>
if(timeBeginPeriod(1) == TIMERR_NOCANDO) {
    printf("TIMER could not be set to 1ms\n");
}
/*-- your code here --*/
timeEndPeriod(1);
```

But this will change the global windows timer resolution to what ever interval you set it to (or at least attempt it), so i wouldn't recommend this approach unless you are 100% certain you are the only one that will use this program as this may have unintended side effects on other programs.

Comment: +1 For use of `QueryPerformanceCounter` and avoiding the use of `RDTSC`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment about the REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, I added the following line in a test program.

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
....

SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

And now the tick count i got from RDTSC looks better, the huge spike I saw before on 1 frame, is now spread over multiple frames.

As i wanted to keep my code portable and create some scheduling opportunities, I yielded the additional thread at some specific point using:

```
boots::this_thread::yield();
```

and with that change, I obtain the scheduling and the RDTSC value I expected without having to configure the priority!

Thank for all help and advice.